# When I use forms authentication and add html attributes to html.beginfom and routeValue object I get nullRefrenceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { returnUrl = @ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery}, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "loginForm" }))
{

   
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    @Html.EditorForModel();
  

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />

}
```

exception :

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
> App_Web_qpa3itia.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

UrlReferrer may be null. Need to handle that case.